# KMeans Clustering of CSV Data Set

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I am trying to create a KMeans clustering model based on a csv data set that I have compiled. The data set is organized as such:

```
              population    longitude   latitude

 Atlanta, GA            
 Austin, TX     
 ...
```

I tried just plotting the data, which isn't working, if produces a scatter plot where you can't see the axis or the data points, and I can't really tell of the Kmeans algorithim is working.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import csv


data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

print (data.head())

plt.scatter(x=data['Population'].astype(bytes), y=data['Longitude'].astype(bytes), z=data["Latitude"].astype(bytes))

plt.xlim(0,1000000)

plt.ylim(0,5000)

plt.zlim(0,5000)

plt.xlabel('Population')

plt.ylabel('Longitude')

plt.zlabel('Latitude')

plt.title('KMeans Clustering for Population vs. Latitude and Longitude', fontsize = 10)

plt.show()

x = data.iloc[:,1:3] #selecting features

#Clustering

kmeans = KMeans(3)

kmeans.fit(x)

#Clustering Results

indentified_clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(x)

indentified_clusters

array([1,1,0.0,2])

data_with_clusters = data.copy()

data_with_clusters['Clusters'] = identified_clusters

plt.scatter(data_with_clusters['Population'],data_with_clusters['Longitude'],data_with_clusters['Latitude']c=data_with_clusters['Clusters'],cmap='rainbow')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#2 Importing the mall dataset
data= pd.read_csv("xxx")


print(data.head())

plt.scatter(data['Longitude'],data['Latitude'])
plt.xlim(-180,180)
plt.ylim(-90,90)
plt.show()


x = data.iloc[:,1:3] # 1t for rows and second for columns
x


kmeans = KMeans(3)
kmeans.fit(x)


data_with_clusters = data.copy()
data_with_clusters['Clusters'] = indentified_clusters 

plt.scatter(data_with_clusters['Longitude'],data_with_clusters['Latitude'],c=data_with_clusters['Clusters'],cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

[image]